# Transit in the UK

Tags: transit

I'm from Indonesia and will travel to the Bahamas, My flight will transit in the UK 7 hours. Do I need transit visa during my transit in the UK?
because according to the UK.gov website '' I won't need a visa to come to the UK'' 
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/indonesia/transit/somewhere_else/no

Please let me know if you can give me valid information

Thank you.

Comment: You already got the official information from the official UK government website. What more can we possibly do?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Indonesian citizenship, you will *not* need a visa if you can do an airside transit. However, you *will* need a visa if you cannot do an airside transit.

Check with your airline or travel agent to find out whether you need to do a landside transit. This might be true if you need to change terminals between flights, for example.